# Storing database pk IDs in php code alternative?

Tags: php, application-design

We have hundreds of thousands of lookup values and since the product is still in dev the IDs are not fixed. So anytime an ID is updated we have to go back and updated thousands of IDs all over the code to make it work properly. It eats away on time.

Is there another method to keep IDs as dynamic in the code so either: they auto update as IDs are changed in the tables, or they are all stored in 1 file for all database tables so it makes updates much easier and quicker from development and testing perspective?

Platform is Mysq + codeignitor php.

Comment: Why are you hardcoding IDs in your code?

Comment: You shouldn't rely on IDs for testing and development

Comment: What else is the alternative? Example is: user status. When they signup they are 'Pending activation' which is ID 1208 in my lookup table. After they confirm they switch to 'Active' which is ID 1209, etc. So my team is hardcoding these IDs 1208, 1209, etc in the code. For testing who else can i test the correct status are changing if i don;t use the correct IDs?

Comment: Use variables in your code that refer to the ids instead of the hard-coded ids themselves.  The variables should be assigned values by pulling the ids from your database.

Comment: @Uri - As AJ says... or even better, use constants rather than variables. And these values should be set once, in one location in your code.

Comment: These variables, are they a column in the DB? If not then where am i linking the variables with the pk IDs?  And is there any slowdown in the queries if i use a pkID directly vs using a variable?

Answer (score 2):

Define constants in your code for the ids instead of hard-coding id values.  Here's an example:

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT Id, Name FROM Product");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    define('ID_'.$row['Name'],$row['Id']);
}
?>
```